# Selenium Python: 'ElementNotInteractableException'

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to `send_keys` to `input` with `id` `model-account-name-input` from this [link](https://surviv.io/). Here is my code:

```py
driver.find_element_by_id('model-account-name-input').click() #Make it reachable by Keyboard
driver.find_element_by_id('model-account-name-input').send_keys('Test')
```

With this code I get the following error: `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="modal-account-name-input" class="menu-option player-name-input" type="text"> could not be scrolled into view`.

Here is an Image of the input I want to `send_keys` to.
[image]

Comment: I can’t find the ID you have mentioned in my location.However if that ID not work try with your ID and the same code.

Answer (score 1):

To Enter Text in text box induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()
and following ID.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://surviv.io/")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"player-name-input-solo"))).send_keys("Test")
```

**Browser snapshot**.

[image]